# Avoid repeat IDs in pivot relation

Tags: mysql

I'm running MySQL v.5.7.

I need to select products with unique (distinct?) advertisers in a many-to-many relationship.

So if a product has one advertiser, the following products should not have the same advertiser.

Here's my example schema:

## Products

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Product 1'),
    (2, 'Product 2'),
    (3, 'Product 3'),
    (4, 'Product 4'),
    (5, 'Product 5'),
    (6, 'Product 6');
```

## Advertisers

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `advertisers` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Advertiser 1'),
    (2, 'Advertiser 2'),
    (3, 'Advertiser 3'),
    (4, 'Advertiser 4'),
    (5, 'Advertiser 5'),
    (6, 'Advertiser 6');
```

## Pivot

```
CREATE TABLE `product_advertisers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `advertiser_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `advertiser_id` (`advertiser_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_advertisers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `product_advertisers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`advertiser_id`) REFERENCES `advertisers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `product_advertisers` (`id`, `product_id`, `advertiser_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 1, 5),
    (3, 2, 1),
    (4, 2, 5),
    (5, 3, 2),
    (6, 4, 1),
    (7, 4, 4),
    (8, 4, 6),
    (9, 5, 3),
    (10, 6, 6),
    (11, 6, 2);
```

Here's the query I'm starting from:

```
SELECT 
    `products`.`id`,
    `products`.`name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`advertisers`.`id`)
FROM
    `products`
        LEFT JOIN `product_advertisers` ON `product_advertisers`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `advertisers` ON `advertisers`.`id` = `product_advertisers`.`advertiser_id`
GROUP BY
    `products`.`id`
;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEYWumW8McpBj6KxFKpGPC/0)

## Results

My observations are manually noted on the last column.

```
| id  | name      | GROUP_CONCAT(`advertisers`.`id`) | Observations
| --- | --------- | -------------------------------- |--------------
| 1   | Product 1 | 2,5                              | 
| 2   | Product 2 | 5,1                              | NOPE! ID 5 appears in Product 1
| 3   | Product 3 | 2                                | NOPE! ID 2 appears in Product 1
| 4   | Product 4 | 1,6,4                            | OK - No conflicts with Product 1
| 5   | Product 5 | 3                                | OK - No conflicts with Products 1 or 4
| 6   | Product 6 | 2,6                              | NOPE! ID 2 appears in Product 1, ID 6 appears in Product 4
```

## Desired Results

```
| id  | name      | GROUP_CONCAT(`advertisers`.`id`) |
| --- | --------- | -------------------------------- |
| 1   | Product 1 | 2,5                              |
| 4   | Product 4 | 1,6,4                            |
| 5   | Product 5 | 3                                |
```